# Ordenar Datatables en DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo una `datatable` con unas fechas y estas no toman el formato de **DD-MM-YYYY** he estado probando de varias formas (sobre todo [esta](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) ) pero no acabo de comprender exactamente el funcionamiento.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabla_clientes').dataTable({

    "aaSorting": [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': [5]
    }]
  });
});
```

Tengo con ese código y se muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me ordena las fechas como fechas sino como si fuera texto. ¿Qué está fallando?

Answer (score 3):

El sort por defecto coge los valores y los ordena, no sabe que te refieres a fechas y al ser string lo hace tal cual.

Si el formato fuera AAAA/MM/DD lo haría bien automáticamente.

Si no te vale eso puedes modificar el algoritmo de ordenación como ves aquí:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/sort()

Sería haciendo algo así como:

```
$('#tabla_clientes')
    .column( 0 )
    .data()
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
```

El - de la función sort depende de si quieres ordenar hacia abajo o hacia arriba.

Un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

Comparto un link con un ejemplo solucionado.
http://live.datatables.net/jirukiga/5/edit